# change to dynamic position CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, position

I have created a box modal but in that all the width, height, position is given by static numbers. I tried giving dynamic(like using percentage) values so that it can adjust in any screen type. But not able to that.

Doing this for mobile app.
Doing this for mobile app.

Can someone please help me in this. Thanks in advance

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <View style={styles.lcircle}></View>
        <View style={styles.rcircle}></View>
        <View style={styles.selectSquare}>SELECT</View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    marginHorizontal: "auto",
    // maxWidth: 500,
    paddingTop: 100
  },
  box: {
    borderColor: "#B9EBC8",
    height: 160,
    width: 180,
    borderWidth: 2
  },
  lcircle: {
    height: 15,
    width: 30,
    borderWidth: 2,
    // borderRadius: 30 30 0 0,
    transform: [{ rotate: "90deg" }],
    borderTopRightRadius: 40,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 40,
    borderRightColor: "#B9EBC8",
    borderTopColor: "#B9EBC8",
    borderLeftColor: "#B9EBC8",
    borderBottomColor: "#FFFFFF",
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: -10
  },
  rcircle: {
    height: 15,
    width: 30,
    borderWidth: 2,
    // borderRadius: 30 30 0 0,
    transform: [{ rotate: "-90deg" }],
    borderTopRightRadius: 40,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 40,
    borderRightColor: "#B9EBC8",
    borderTopColor: "#B9EBC8",
    borderLeftColor: "#B9EBC8",
    borderBottomColor: "#FFFFFF",
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: 155.5
  },
  selectSquare: {
    height: 40,
    width: 100,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "#B9EBC8",
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    position: "absolute",
    left: 40,
    top: 135,
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    color: "#008C00"
  }
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Your styles.app has no height so it's possible that your styles.box is inheriting the height. Set the styles.app to span the height of the screen and then set the style.box height to 100% : https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-scott-or842z

Comment: @RyanZeelie thats fine, but what about others

Comment: Check the codeSanbox . I updated previous comment

Comment: @RyanZeelie its has just increased the height

Comment: Then I guess I misunderstood what you meant by "adjust in any screen type". Since that's what the code does

Comment: @RyanZeelie as the screen size changes the box size should also change. Means responsive

Comment: The entire box is responsive. Width and height. Check the sandbox